# Trying to draw on a Picture Box, but nothing appears

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I'm converting a VB6 application to VB.Net that draws on picture boxes. Naturally I read the fine manual and turn up this example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dtfzwyx(v=vs.71).aspx). I therefore produced a little project with a form containing only a picture box and tried the following:-

```
Private Sub Picture1_paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
            Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim mygraphics As Graphics
    mygraphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
    Dim pen As New Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 1)
    mygraphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 0, 0, 100, 100)
    pen.Dispose
End Sub
```

just like it says. But on running the application, the box turns up blank. Searching for help turned up a suggestion [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131226033137/http://bobpowell.net/picturebox.aspx) that I should use a `Frame` instead, but the result was the same. I have checked that I'm not drawing in the background colour, and that the function is actually invoked.

What have I overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paint handler has invalid type for `EventArgs`. It should be `System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs`

Use `e.Graphics` property to obtain graphics instance.

```
 mygraphics = e.Graphics
```

Reference Link [MSDN - Control.Paint Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx#Y444)

Answer (score 1):

I think `e` is of `PainEventArgs` type, with already contains a graphics object in `e.Graphics`. Use that instead.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

        Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 0, 0, 100, 100)
        pen.Dispose()

    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: Screenshot]